# Data type mismatch in criteria expression ERROR Coming

Tags: ms-access-2007, vb.net-2010

This is my code for add data.but no data can insert to database newly because error coming
 and say  Data type mismatch in criteria expression.Why is that?????????

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

Dim con As OleDbConnection
Dim myAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication9\WindowsApplication9\NIBM.accdb")
    con.Open()
    myAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO Driverdetails values(@DriverNo,@DriverName,@DriverAge,@DriverAddress)", con)

    myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Driver No", TextBox1.Text)
    myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Driver Name", TextBox2.Text)
    myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Driver Age", TextBox3.Text)
    myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Driver Address", TextBox4.Text)



    myAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: None of your parameter names match up to their `AddWithValue` counterparts.

Comment: What do you mean by that??

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you've introduced spaces into the parameter names: `@Driver No`

**Added** Access requires the field-names to be specified with the INSERT INTO statement (when used to insert a single record). [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

> You can use the INSERT INTO statement to add a single record to a
>   table using the single-record append query syntax as shown above. In
>   this case, your code specifies the name and value for each field of
>   the record. You must specify each of the fields of the record that a
>   value is to be assigned to and a value for that field. When you do not
>   specify each field, the default value or Null is inserted for missing
>   columns. Records are added to the end of the table.

Comment: myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DriverNo", TextBox1.Text)
        myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DriverName", TextBox2.Text)
        myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DriverAge", TextBox3.Text)
        myAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DriverAddress", TextBox4.Text)
But still not working??????bro

Comment: I've added to my answer.